# Is it possible to connect to a Socket.IO server from static JavaScript on another server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

Apologies if this is a bizarre or confusing question. I'm developing an application that doesn't use any server-side technology; it's just static HTML and JavaScript content. Part of this application involves managing real-time messages passed between multiple clients (i.e. chat). Various requirements and restrictions led me to settle on using Node.js and Socket.IO as a server managing the messages.

My problem is that, due to a client from hell refusing to budge, the actual client web page needs to be served as direct-linked static content on one server, and the Node.js server needs to be hosted and run separately. A normal Socket.IO setup involves detecting clients connecting and requesting pages from the Node.js server, and a `socket.io.js` file is provided to those clients, which exposes access to `io()` and all the things necessary to make everything actually work.

Because the pages that need to connect to Socket.IO aren't being served by the Node.js server, that obviously won't work, so is there any way to somehow have a client page connect to a Socket.IO instance without being on the same server? I know I can use a simpler and more straightforward solution like AJAX, but I feel that Socket.IO better fits my needs and I'd like to make it work if possible.

Comment: @apsillers I think it's either very similar or a duplicate, but either way the accepted answer seems to be what I'm looking for. Thanks for the link!

Comment: Additional similar question that might be helpful: [Connecting client to server using Socket.io](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9945693/connecting-client-to-server-using-socket-io)